# how to print a certain amount of characters before a string in python

Tags: python, python-3.4

hi i have a python script that is going to a website and searching for strings inside of certain tags and printing it. my screen will look like this after it prints it -  textidontwant textiwanthere.com 
how can i search for the .com and print a number of characters before it to only get the textiwanthere.com to show up instead of all of it. here is my code -

```
import urllib.request
import re
import os

url = "http://www.throwawaymail.com/"

request = urllib.request.Request(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
sourcecode = urllib.request.urlopen(request).read()
output = sourcecode.decode("utf-8")

findemail = re.findall('>(.*?)</span>', str(output))

print(findemail)

os.system("pause")
```

i want to search "findemail" for it
 i want to print the phamepracl@throwam.com but its different everytime but the length is the same this is what my console says -

['Toggle navigation', '', '', '', '', 'phamepracl@throwam.com']

Answer (score 1):

Just print the last entry of the list

```
print(findemail[-1])
```

You could also assign this value to `findmail` if you don't want the other stuff

```
findemail = re.findall('>(.*?)</span>', str(output))[-1]
```

This worked for me:

```
import urllib.request
import re
import os

url = "http://www.throwawaymail.com/"

request = urllib.request.Request(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
sourcecode = urllib.request.urlopen(request).read()
output = sourcecode.decode("utf-8")

findemail = re.findall('>(.*?)</span>', str(output))

print(findemail[-1])
```

Comment: this did not work and gave me this error - list index out of range

Comment: @john.crem Are you sure you modified the script correctly? It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

This is my solution:

```
for i in findemail:
    if i.find('.com')>=0:
        print(i)
```

Output:

```
hudininona@throwam.com
```